# How to get dropdown menu to work on Statelesswidget

Tags: redux, flutter

I using redux for flutter so every presentation is stateless but i can't get dropdown menu to work property since i can't change it's state to trigger flutter to rebuild the dropdown part when choose value from dropdown.

I trying to implement dropdown menu for [this](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples/blob/master/example/redux/lib/presentation/add_edit_screen.dart) screen.

My code look something like this:

```
List<String> _suppliers = <String>['Apple', 'Google'];
String _supplier = 'Apple';

...

DropdownButton(
              key: _supplierKey,
              value: _supplier,
              items: _suppliers.map((String value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                _supplier = newValue;
              }),
...
```

I don't know if i implemented it right or anyway to workaround? Any help would be appreciate. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

I can see two options here:

- Store that value in the state, and dispatch action on every dropdown change.

or

- If for some reason you don't want that value in redux state, create a Stateless Widget and store that value inside the State object. You will use `setState()` method to update it, when you will be ready to send it into state, then just do it the normal way :)